# plt.imsave saves image incorrectly

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am trying to generate the CLEVR dataset with some random images of rectangles and circle. When I am debugging the code for every `plt.imshow()` statement I can see a new image with the shape generated alongwith the shapes generated in the last executed loops. Although, to my surprise everytime the 5th image generated never shows during the debugging mode.

Also when I save the images locally I see only two objects. Please find the images for reference purposes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

colors = [
    (0, 0, 255),      # r
    (0, 255, 0),      # g
    (255, 0, 0),      # b
    (0, 156, 255),    # o
    (128, 128, 128),  # k
    (0, 255, 255)     # y
]

img_size = 75
size = 5

def center_generate(objects):
    while True:
        pas = True
        center = np.random.randint(0+size, img_size - size, 2)        
        if len(objects) > 0:
            for name, c, shape in objects:
                """this condition checks if the new object generated is not completely covered by the already 
            generated objects"""
                if ((center - c) ** 2).sum() < ((size * 2) ** 2):
                    pas = False
        if pas:
            return center

def build_dataset(dataset_type, loopnumber):
    objects = []
    img = np.ones((img_size, img_size, 3)) * 255
    for color_id, color in enumerate(colors):
        center = center_generate(objects)
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            start = (center[0]-size, center[1]-size)
            end = (center[0]+size, center[1]+size)
            img = cv2.rectangle(img, start, end, color, -1)
            plt.imshow(img)
            objects.append((color_id, center, 'r'))
        else:
            center_ = (center[0], center[1])
            img = cv2.circle(img, center_, size, color, -1)
            plt.imshow(img)
            objects.append((color_id, center, 'c'))

        if dataset_type == 'test':
            plt.imsave('..\\img\\test\\img_' + str(loop) + '.jpeg', img)
        else:
            plt.imsave('..\\img\\train\\img_' + str(loop) + '.jpeg', img)
```

The image generated during debugging.
[image: Image generated during debugging]

Image stored locally.

[image: Image saved locally]

Could anyone explain the issue here?
Thanks

Comment: What is img_size, center_generate?

Comment: @MohitMotwani image size is 75 and center_generate is just a function to generate center of the object. I will update the center_generate code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the image use `cv2.imwrite()`:

```
cv2.imwrite('..\\img\\train\\img_' + str(loop) + '.jpeg', img)
```

Also to correctly save it with `plt.imsave`, you need to divide by `255`:

```
plt.imsave('..\\img\\train\\img_' + str(loop) + '.jpeg', img/255.0)
```

or convert them to `'uint8'`:

```
img = img.astype('uint8')
plt.imsave('..\\img\\train\\img_' + str(loop) + '.jpeg', img)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please tell why dividing by 255 makes it happen?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. I googled a bit and some trial and error helped.

Comment: Okay, no problem. I will try to find it out. Thank you anyway!